# Find article body with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find the article body element on a set of differently structured web pages.
The only common property of all those pages is that the article body element is holding the largest amount of child elements of type `<p>`.
What is the jQuery code or selector that allows me to find the element with the largest number of `<p>` child elements?

Comment: When you want to analysize external webpages you need a Server side language not a client side one.

Comment: There is no built-in selector to do this. You'll have to count the specific elements and then take the largest. You can use the `length` property of a set of matched elements to know how many child elements it contains.

Comment: That will be a very expensive selector. Consider another option which makes more sense.

Comment: @mimo - not necessarily true. This might be a browser plugin - in that case it would only need client side technologies.

Comment: You can assume that my code is running locally inside all those pages. I want a generic solution.

Comment: Define _the article body element_! is that a class? ID?

Comment: I thought about selecting all `<p>` elements and looping over them, looking at the parent element. Counting the number of times I meet each parent, and finding the largest one. Would that be efficient enough?

Comment: The element that includes the article content is different on each web page. There's no id or class I can query for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one way to go about this.

```
$(function() {
    var biggest_div = $('div').first()
    $('div').each(function() {
        console.log(biggest_div);
        if ( $(this).children('p').length > biggest_div.children('p').length ) {
            biggest_div = $(this);
        }
    });
    $(biggest_div).addClass('highlight')
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qecnsff4/)

Answer (score 2):

The red div is the one with the most `p` children elements.

**EXPLANATION**

1. Set a new counter variable equal to zero (i)
2. Loop through the `.section` elements and get the length of `p` elements
3. Set this number as `data-p` attribute to the current element
4. If this is greater than the counter, set the counter equal to this number
5. Use the final `i` to apply the `.article` class

```js
var i = 0;
$('.section').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var p = that.children('p').length;
  if (p > i) {
    i = p;
  }
  that.attr('data-p', p);
});
$('[data-p=' + i + ']').addClass('article');
```

```css
.section {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:10px;
}
.article { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>A paragraph</p><p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>A paragraph</p>  
</div>
<div class="section">
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks :)